# How to run an sql query on an OpenOffice/LibreOffice spreadsheet from command line?

Tags: sql, csv, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic, openoffice-base

Well,

The title pretty much says it all. I have a set of ODS spreadsheets and I want to run some SQL queries over these spreadsheets and save the result on CSV files.

I know I can do that from the GUI, but I need to be able to do it from a batch file that will be run on a regular basis.

Solutions that make use of OpenOffice/LibreOffice Basic are acceptable, as well as solutions that require the use of some (free) plug-in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please expand on how to do that via the GUI? Maybe in a different question or as a doc item.

Answer (score 1):

You could first convert `.ods` files into `.csv` files and do what you have to do on `.csv` files (insert in a real database, read it as plain text, etc.).

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv *.ods
```